# Using independence number of a graph to prove inequality statement

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, coloring

The independence number of a graph $G$, denoted $α(G)$, is the maximum number $k$ such that
$G$ contains a set of $k$ nonadjacent vertices. Noting that “color classes” are sets of nonadjacent
vertices, explain why it must be the case that $χ(G) ≥ \dfrac{|V(G))|}{α(G)}$

So when I started looking at this problem, I first decided to test some graphs that we know the $χ(G)$ of like $P_3$, $C_4$, and $C_5$. Here is the RHS of the inequality I got for these given I understand correctly.

$P_3$ = $\dfrac{3}{2}$

$C_4$ = $\dfrac{4}{2}$

$C_5$ = $\dfrac{5}{5}$

All of these are less than two, so I can see a couple of examples of inequality being true.

I figure the reason for this inequality has to be in some part due to the graph's chromatic value, but I am having trouble seeing why exactly. Is there a theorem about the graph's chromatic number that would help me approach this problem or am I just missing something?

Comment: Maybe it will be clearer if you write the inequality in the form $|V(G)|\le\chi(G)\alpha(G)$.

Comment: Hi @elemelons, sorry for the duplicate. I did not see that. I will delete this post.